# Custom notification marquee text doesnt work android

Tags: android, android-notifications

Hi im trying to make part of my text in the notification manager marquee but doesnt work i tried this:

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"                                     
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"              
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
  </TextView>
```

and in my .java i use remoteview:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);

contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title_text, "This is a very long text which is not fitting in the screen so it needs to be marqueed");
```

i would like to have marquee for that title_text **This is a very long text which is not fitting in the screen so it needs to be marqueed**

but the marquee doesnt work just stays static what i can do?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lost a day to realize thats the marquee effect is done by this method from [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification): [setTicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setTicker%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29) which support RemoteView

I really hope that answer save many lives :) (almost lost my hair)

Comment: not when using .setCustomBigContentView(remoteViewsSetFromCustomLayout)

Comment: /**
         * Sets the "ticker" text which is sent to accessibility services. Prior to
         * {@link Build.VERSION_CODES#LOLLIPOP}, sets the text that is displayed in the status bar
         * when the notification first arrives, and also a RemoteViews object that may be displayed
         * instead on some devices.
         */

Answer (score 11):

i changed my xml:

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"                                     
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"              
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:textColor="#fff">
    <requestFocus/> 
  </TextView>
```

i added `<requestFocus/>` and now my marquee works perfect.

Comment: just because i'm curious, would you try setting the scrollHorizontally back to true and see if it works?

Comment: works if i set it to true but if i remove `<requestFocus/>` doesnt work at all.

Comment: it's very useful. i try to solve this problem about 4 days :-D

Comment: From what I've read, it appears marquee only works whenever the target text field is selected.  Which is why this works :)

Comment: It does work, but I need to try to expand the notification in order to start. even with the requestFocus.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHorizontallyScrolling%28boolean%29), setting the scrollHorizontally attribute to true will NOT wrap the text at the edge. Try setting it to false so the ellipsize attribute is used.

Comment: doesnt work :( i set it to false but same the marquee doesnt work