# How can I activate text marquee on a TextView?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, remoteview

I want to have a TextView with the marquee effect in my RemoteView

I have this layout XML describing the layout of my RemoteView (R.layout.notification_loading_small):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="64dip"
              android:background="@color/primary_background_inverted">

    <ProgressBar android:indeterminate="true"
                 android:layout_width="64dip"
                 android:layout_height="64dip"
                 android:id="@+id/marker_progress" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notification_small_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_textcolor_inverted"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
            android:text="@string/loading"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notification_small_textview2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_textcolor_inverted"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
            android:text="@string/loading_advice"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And a method in my Java like this:

```
public void createTestNotification() {
        mSmallLoadingNotificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_loading_small);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                PlayerService.this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification).setContentTitle(APP_NAME)
                .setOngoing(true).setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContent(mSmallLoadingNotificationView);

        mNotification = builder.build();

        startForeground(PLAYERSERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
}
```

I want to make the text in **id/notification_small_textview2** to marquee horizontally, but it seems like an impossible task so far...

According to the Internet I need to add *android:ellipsize="marquee"*, *android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"*, *android:lines="1"* and *android:singleLine="true"* in my TextView. It also seems that we need to call the method **setSelected(true)** from the TextView in Java. However I cannot find a way to do this in that method... What am I missing?

**How should I modify my Java code in order for the marquee to work?**

Answer (score 3):

I think the marquee way is going to work only if the text display length is going to be bigger than the width of the `TextView`, and since you set it up as `match_parent`, it needs to be a really long  text.

Also, you need to set the focusable properties.
I tried it with the following:

```
<TextView
    android:text="Some string here that is wider than your screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

If your string is not long enough, the first thing that comes to mind is animating the `TextView` left and right. Or maybe implementing your custom `TextView` that draws text with an offset.

Comment: I can assure that the string in the TeztView is larger than the width. However I put it there using Java instead of using XML. I will try with the focusable.

Comment: Does not work, even with     android:layout_width="match_parent", I think the issue here is the RemoteView context.

Comment: I miss the old times where <marquee></marquee> would do the trick with no fuss.

Comment: yes, I think you're right about `RemoteViews`. Check out these links and see if anything there works: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990405/custom-notification-marquee-text-doesnt-work-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990405/custom-notification-marquee-text-doesnt-work-android) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765150/why-is-marquee-not-working-in-widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765150/why-is-marquee-not-working-in-widget)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what you can do with notifications, but if the problem is related to the TextView you may be able to use a WebView instead with some HTML.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17007724/3545278